# Need to reformat Quarterly Date in SQL Server: 2021-Q2 should be shown as “Q2 / 21”

Tags: sql-server, ssms, date-formatting

Example: I have a column which have values in the format of `2021-Q2`.

How do I reformat those values to the format `Q2/21`?

I had tried `substring`.

Comment: *"I had tried substring"* And what was wrong with `SUBSTRING`? That seems like it would work.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @InString varchar(10)='2021-Q2'

select RIGHT(@InString,2)+'/'+RIGHT(LEFT(@InString,4),2);
```